# How to delete your own answer?

Tags: support, answers, self-delete

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that-actually-mean)

I can't seem to find any way to do this.

Comment: It'd help if you told us which answer. Have you got a link?

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that-actually-mean for details on when you are allowed to delete your own answer. (can't delete them if you're not registered, can't delete them if accepted)

Comment: I don't see where in the linked "duplicate" question it explains why we aren't allowed always to delete our own content. :(

Answer (score 49):

There should be a delete link under your answer - click it!

[image: Delete Link]

Or, if you're using the mobile app:

[image]

Comment: I get link and edit but no delete :(

Comment: @user143150 - you must be logged in in order to delete your own posts.

Comment: Strangely this answer has 0 votes... trying to upvote it doesn't work either

Comment: Does deleting your own answer affects something in your own account?

Comment: it 'reclaims' reputation if rated very low.

Comment: Stack Exchange owns everything you post, and will never give you the power to completely, permanently scrub embarrassing evidence of your past ignorance or a psychotic episode. Sufficiently empowered users will always be able to access it against your desire to lock it in seven chests and drown it in the sea.

Answer (score 16):

You can't delete an accepted answer.