# User wants to delete his answer but can't

Tags: support, answers, vote-to-delete, specific-answer

The user that posted this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20884445/66686

wants it deleted, but he can't delete it (he says in the comments). I can only vote for deletion so my questions would be:

a) what is needed for a user to delete his answer? Or is this behavior a bug?

b) (Done) can you help delete this specific answer, since the author doesn't want it, and it is not of much use for the site

Comment: dup? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38937/how-to-delete-your-own-answer?rq=1

Comment: Or is the OP confused by this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79683/rules-for-deleting-my-own-answers?rq=1

Comment: That seems strange. It should generally be always possible to delete you answer.

Comment: [meta-tag:status-bydesign]?

Comment: Looks gone to me.

Comment: @Pëkka I think you can't delete accepted answers, but that doesn't seem to be the case here.